# When updating a package version, what should the license year be?

Tags: licensing, mit, license

When creating a new R package version under an existing MIT licence, should the year be [creation_year], [current_year] or [creation_year - current_year]?

Answer (score 10):

The year in a copyright notice is the first year that a work has been published. A work can be the original software, or it can be the *changes* to a piece of software, assuming that those are significant enough to be protected by copyrights.

If, in a particular year, you have made significant enough changes to the package, you are entitled to add another copyright line to the existing set of copyright lines.

To avoid having a long list of very similar copyright lines like

> copyright <year1> Author
> copyright <year2> Author
> copyright <year3> Author
> copyright <year4> Author

it is possible to merge the lines containing copyright statement for the same author, like

> copyright <year1>, <year2>, <year3>, <year4> Author

And if that list of years gets too long, you can merge several *consecutive* years into a range.
For example, if there is a gap between year1 and year2, but the other are all consecutive, the copyright line can also be written as

> copyright <year1>, <year2> - <year4> Author

Comment: I've not come across this before.  Most instances I've seen have been `[start year] - [current year]`.  Is this just your personal opinion, or can you link to some documentation that backs this up as recommended best-practice?

Comment: @HappyDog, in the US copyright law, I can only find the first form with a single year (year of first publication). The other forms are based on what I encountered in various projects. Just a range would be a special case of the last form I showed where all years are consecutive.

Comment: There are two questions here - I'm not sure if the OP is asking both or just the former.  The first question is which dates should be referenced in a copyright notice.  The second is what is the appropriate format for the copyright notice.  In terms of the former, your answer seems to say that you should include each year where significant changes are made, but not years where no significant changes are made.  That is interesting, but I still think it needs backing-up by some references.

Comment: Also, if there are no ramifications for including a year when not much coding happened, then `Y1 - YN` seems like the safe option, assuming that is an acceptable way of representing it.  I would probably do that rather than having to cherry-pick the interesting years, which seems like more work with no advantage (...and potentially a risk, if the omission of years is seen as somehow significant to a legal argument).

Comment: @HappyDog, I am not sure what you mean with "cherry-pick the interesting years". If it is an interesting year or not should at the latest be known at the end of the year and as soon as you know it is interesting you can add/update the copyright notice. Mentioning a year too many or too few probably does not have significant consequences, as the copyright does not expire until 70 years after the authors death anyway.

Comment: I just meant that if you did developed the software in 2020, did no work at all in 2021 and then developed it further in 2022, rather than cherry-picking those development years, and having `(c) copyright 2020...` and `(c) copyright 2022...` I would just update the end year, to end up with `(c) copyright 2020-2022...`.  It's easier to manage, more succinct and means you don't have to make a decision about whether those small tweaks you made in 2023 warrant adding an extra year to the copyright notice; you just update the end year the first time you make some (any) edits in a given year.

Comment: @HappyDog, while that is not the correct way to do it, I acknowledge that it is an easy way and that it probably gets done a lot.

Comment: `"that is not the correct way to do it"`... You might be right, but I'll repeat my earlier question - can you link to some documentation that backs this up?  If you can't cite any sources, then I'm not sure I'd give much credence to this as an answer as it feels like it's just an opinion, in its current form.

Comment: @HappyDog, Here is the relevant section from the US Copyright law: https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap4.html#401. More definitive that that you can't get.

Comment: Yeah - that's pretty good.  I think that would be worth referencing in your answer, as comments can sometimes be lost.